# Moving database file locations in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 Express edition installed on my machine. I had changed the location of some folders from one drive to another (from F: to E:).

Now when I connect to SQL Server using SSMS, it does not show any database. If I try to attach a database by selecting the file it show me the error that

> *Cannot attach a database with the same name as an existing database*

How can I clean up the no-existing (for SQL Server) databases and re-attach the moved files?

Edit:- In Event Log it is showing errors like following for moved databases:

```
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file F:\Code\EFTest\App_Data\eftest.mdf for 
file number 0.  OS error: 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. 
Reason: 15105).
```

`master`, `model`,`msdb`,`tempdb` databases are available as these are in default location. The unavailable databases were in custom locations (in moved folder).

Comment: Is the `master` database still available in SSMS when connecting to the server?

Comment: @marc_s the database is not visible or available in query window.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes the system databases are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that all you need to do is issue the following command for each `user` database that was moved:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_name, FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name' );
```

I grabbed that line of code from [these instructions published by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx). So read those too.

Comment: thanks @Michael Perrenoud this worked. But after restarting database server it is showing `eftest (Recovery Pending)` in object explorer.

Comment: That means that SQL cannot run restart recovery on that database for some reason.  A common reason is that the log file is missing or corrupt.  Did you run the above statement for the log file as well? If the log file was also moved (.ldf) it will require the same MODIFY FILE statement

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the database really does exist, but is just not mounted; does it show up when you carefully refresh the object explorer in SSMS, or when you look at sys.databases?

```
SELECT * FROM Sys.databases;
```

If it appears in either place, you'll want to make sure you've backed up the files safely, then DROP the database.  Once it's dropped, you can ATTACH the files you've backed up after moving them where you want.

The SQL Server error log will tell you what SQL Server is trying to do about the database when you start the server instance. Showing the log entries for the database that appear at server start up would probably be helpful.